# Why 2 columns of the same value give different total?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, regexextract, copy-paste

[Sample Data in Result Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uO6mw6T9vK9mN8ZRtCJXX5UT8yV_rL-4_fD2TZbiDbk/edit#gid=1804681073)

I have a formula in A2 that extracts data & splits it into unit & product (A & B).
I used the SUMIF formula to give the the total of each separate set of product from A, but got value 0.

So then I converted the COl A into values in Col. C, and using sum if on that gives me the correct total.

Why can't I get the correct sum directly from A?

[image]

Comment: As you will surely have already understood, the answer to your question is: because column A contains texts and not numbers. In fact, you would like to add something very similar to: a + a + c + b ... not containing any number, the result is 0